# Tableau rounds my numbers to 16 decimals on import. How can I stop this?

Tags: tableau-api

When connecting to a data source and importing data into Tableau decimals are limited to 16 places. I have large decimals that are being multiplied by millions of products so these rounding errors are affecting my end calculations.

I made sure the data type is coming in as Number (decimal).

I would like the data to be imported into Tableau un-rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau, like [Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/), uses floating point precision for its numbering system.

This means that Tableau will only provide 15 digits of precision for numbers.

If this were for display purposes, I would suggest bringing the numbers in as strings. [See this similar answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360109/downloading-tableau-data-into-excel-scientific-notation-column/55370182#55370182) However, because mathematical operations are being performed, the precision is unavoidable.

If possible:

1. Perform mathematical operations elsewhere. For example, a custom SQL query that will bring the table to Tableau with operations already complete.
2. Try to operate in a smaller scale - instead of multiplying by millions, multiply by hundreds/thousands and change the name of the field to represent the scale. (ie: 'thousands of millions' instead of billions.) [Something like this perhaps](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDPC1).